# Passing information after a page redirect in express without cookies

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Right now, after a successful login, I have something along the lines of:

```
app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
    logger.debug("(login.js ) - IN LOGIN NOW");
    var minute = 60 * 1000;
    res.cookie('_id', req.params.id, {
        maxAge: minute
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

where the redirect would send a file like this:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/../public/index.html'));
```

I am wondering if I want to pass in user information (like age, occupation etc), is there any way to do it while sending the html file without using cookies as a way to store the variables?

Comment: If this isn't ajax call You probably want to use something like res.render('index', {user: user}); but this requires you to put the index.html into views folder and inside that file you have access to user variable something like <p>{{user.age}}</p>

Comment: How about storing user information inside a session? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session